# Can't push LWC to a scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-web-components

When I create a Litghtning Web Component and click push, component does not push to an org and "All Up To Date" message received.
Does anybody know how to fix it?[image]

Comment: Is API version of project/module 45?

Comment: Yes, it is. I've tried not sfdx project and there it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

From your screenshot I see you have a `__tests__` folder, which I assume contains some Jest unit test related code. The `__tests__` folder and it's content cannot be pushed to your orgs and should be ignored by modifying the `.forceignore` file in your project.

Add a `**/__tests__/**` entry to the top level `.forceignore` file and try again.

See how the ebikes-lwc sample project does it [here](https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc/blob/master/.forceignore#L14).